# Testing ordered CRUD in jUnit

Tags: java, testing, junit, jboss-arquillian

I want to test CRUD operations in my `jUnit` tests. I'd like to do that in some order, where `testCreate`  would insert the record into the database, and `testRead`, `testUpdate`, `testDelete` would work on the data that `testCreate` has already inserted. Now I am trying to do something like this.

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public abstract class UserPersistenceTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    protected UserTransaction utx;

    protected Collection<User> entities;

    @Rule
    public ExternalResource resource = new ExternalResource() {
        @Override
        protected void before() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Setting up resource");
            entities = generateEntities(); // returns a list of User
            prepareTests();
        }
        @Override
        protected void after() {
            System.out.println("Cleaning up resource");
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (SystemException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        return Deployments.createDeployment();
    }

    public void prepareTests() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();

        System.out.println("Inserting records...");

        for (User e : entities) {
            entityManager.persist(e);
        }
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        entityManager.joinTransaction();
    }



    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {
        // insert records
        for (User e : entities) {
            entityManager.persist(e);
        }

        // validate that they're there
        testRead();
    }


    @Test
    public void testRead() {
        JPAQuery q = new JPAQuery(entityManager);

        List<User> retrieved = q.from(e).list(e);

        Assert.assertEquals(entities.size(), retrieved.size());
        Assert.assertTrue(retrieved.containsAll(entities));
    }
```

Now the strange thing about it that `READ,UPDATE,DELETE` test don't work if I don't insert the records **prior** to the test-cases, ie. method `prepareTests()`. They simply don't see the inserted records, like there was some sort of automatic rollback. `CREATE` works. However, if the records are inserted prior to `CREATE`, everything will work.

My question is, why do other tests not "see" the change that `testCreate` has done (inserted the records)? I verified that it actually runs before other tests. But they normally see it if `before()` method inserts them.

What is going on here? How can I make my other tests aware of `testCreate` is inserting?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the "some sort of automatic rollback" is your implementation of the `after`-Method of the `ExternalResource`.

This method gets executed after every test (method, not class), see [here](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html) for example.

So you're doing basically

```
before() <-Insert's done here
testCreate() <- More Insert's done here
after() <- Rollback happens here
before() <- Insert's done here again
testRead() <- Insert's from testCreate have been rolled back in last after()
after() <- Rollback again
```

As you see the records inserted by testCreate are rollbacked before testRead() happens.

If you'd want to do something like you suggested you could rollback the transcation in an `@AfterClass` method (and insert in `@BeforeClass`)

Another alternative would be to insert the records in the `before`()-Method of the `ExternalResource`